# Rebuilding node from scratch

Tags: node, baking-node

If I blow up my node and start from scratch and create a new identity, will I lose my future bakes/endorsements that I had earned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tezos baking and endorsing rights are assigned on a snapshot basis, meaning whatever address you are staking with is snapshoted into the network.

So no, You won’t lose your rights as long as you reuse the same wallet. You’ll want to make sure the node is synced before hand so it can bake and endorse on your behalf.